# Salesforce Mobile SDK sync limitations

Tags: mobile, salesforce, salesforce-mobile-sdk

I am developing native android mobile application using Salesforce Mobile SDK. Is there any limitations to sync the records from/to server. It will reflect in salesforce Rest API limitations ? Help please.